# Remote debug a JUnit test executed using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, junit, remote-debugging

I have the following scenario:

Machine A: Executing a JUnit test using Gradle:

```
./gradlew :<directory> --tests <ClassName> --info
```

Machine B: I have an IDE (like IntelliJ). I want to create a remote Java debug configuration to machine A and debug the test.

I came across "**--debug-jvm**" option for gradlew for remote debug. Using this parameter, the Gradle test runner is getting suspended on port 5005 by default. I can connect to this process only from the same machine (machine A) but not from machine B.

I followed the steps mentioned at https://www.thomaskeller.biz/blog/2020/11/17/debugging-with-gradle/
But even with this configuration, I am unable to debug from machine B. I always get "Connection refused" error from the IDE in machine B.

With Gradle's --info option, I can see the following parameters added to JVM started for running the tests:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

For remote debugging I believe address should have "*:" before the port number. For example:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005
```

But the "--debug-jvm" is not adding "*:" to the parameters.

Also tried the following things:

1. Adding "debugOptions" to the Gradle's "test" task:

   **debugOptions {
   enabled = true
   port = 8166
   server = true
   suspend = true
   }**

The result is the same. Not able to connect from machine B and results in "Connection refused" error in IDE.

2. Adding following properties to gradle.proprties:

`org.gradle.daemon=false`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:10999
```

Gradle's daemon thread is suspended with the above properties but not the test executor thread.

Gradle version: **5.6.2**
Java version: **JDK 11**

Things are working if everything (running the tests and IDE) is on a single machine.

So the question is, how to really "remote" debug a JUnit test that is executed using Gradle?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The--debug-jvm option is designed to allow remote debugging but has broken since JDK 9. Refer to this: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7496.

One workaround is to use jvmArgs in Gradle's **test** task to give it the exact debug arguments you want. This worked for me (you may replace 30069 with any free port).

Exmaple:

```
jvmArgs '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:30069'
```